# How to upgrade android on Sony xperia tablet z using ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, android, tablet, sony

My Sony Xperia tablet Z need an android upgrade but I really don't know how to do it using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, Settings > About Tablet > Updates... You don't need a computer.

Comment: yes but it says 10.3.1.A.0.244 - computer required